# zoom effect function with moviepy

Tags: python, moviepy

i have many images are resized at 720x1280, so when I try to apply this zoom effect function to generate clips with moviepy

```
def zoom_in_effect(clip, zoom_ratio=0.025):
    def effect(get_frame, t):
        img = Image.fromarray(get_frame(t))
        base_size = img.size

        new_size = [
            math.ceil(img.size[0] * (1 + (zoom_ratio * t))),
            math.ceil(img.size[1] * (1 + (zoom_ratio * t)))
        ]

        # The new dimensions must be even.
        new_size[0] = new_size[0] + (new_size[0] % 2)
        new_size[1] = new_size[1] + (new_size[1] % 2)
        
        img = img.resize(new_size, Image.LANCZOS)

        x = math.ceil((new_size[0] - base_size[0]) / 2)
        y = math.ceil((new_size[1] - base_size[1]) / 2)

        img = img.crop([
            x, y, new_size[0] - x, new_size[1] - y
        ]).resize(base_size, Image.LANCZOS)

        result = numpy.array(img)
        img.close()

        return result

    return clip.fl(effect)
```

sometimes this function return an error

***operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1280,720) (1280,720,3)***

Answer (score -1):

```py
import moviepy.editor as mp
import math
from PIL import Image
import numpy


def zoom_in_effect(clip, zoom_ratio=0.04):
    def effect(get_frame, t):
        img = Image.fromarray(get_frame(t))
        base_size = img.size

        new_size = [
            math.ceil(img.size[0] * (1 + (zoom_ratio * t))),
            math.ceil(img.size[1] * (1 + (zoom_ratio * t)))
        ]

        # The new dimensions must be even.
        new_size[0] = new_size[0] + (new_size[0] % 2)
        new_size[1] = new_size[1] + (new_size[1] % 2)

        img = img.resize(new_size, Image.LANCZOS)

        x = math.ceil((new_size[0] - base_size[0]) / 2)
        y = math.ceil((new_size[1] - base_size[1]) / 2)

        img = img.crop([
            x, y, new_size[0] - x, new_size[1] - y
        ]).resize(base_size, Image.LANCZOS)

        result = numpy.array(img)
        img.close()

        return result

    return clip.fl(effect)


size = (1920, 1080)

img = 'https://www.colorado.edu/cumuseum/sites/default/files/styles/widescreen/public/slider/coachwhip2_1.jpg'

slide = mp.ImageClip(img).set_fps(25).set_duration(10).resize(size)
slide = zoom_in_effect(slide, 0.04)

slide.write_videofile('zoom-test-2.mp4')
```

Comment: @RajanRank I don't think you understood what I was trying to say. There are times when this function works, but sometimes it generates this error (operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1280,720) (1280,720,3))